# Mesh Error: getUsedCollateral not implemented

Tags: smart-contract, mesh

I'm using mesh and follow [this](https://mesh.martify.io/apis/transaction/smart-contract) example of always-succeed smartcontract.

I successfully send Lovelace to the script address. But when building transaction for redeeming Lovelace from the script address, there comes this error:

```
Error: [Transaction] An error occurred during build: Error: getUsedCollateral not implemented..
at Object.build (/root/meshapp/node_modules/@martifylabs/mesh/dist/mesh.cjs:1:51612)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Everything is like the example except:

1. I use App Wallet (Example: Browser Wallet)
2. I send Lovelace (Example: 64af286...)
3. I use preview testnet (Example: preprod, I guess)

The error occur when building the transaction with

```
const tx = new Transaction({ initiator: wallet })
.redeemValue({
    value: assetUtxo,
    script: {
        version: 'V1',
        code: '4e4d01000033222220051200120011',
    },
    datum: '0000007',
})
.sendValue(address, assetUtxo)
.setRequiredSigners([address]);

const unsignedTx = await tx.build();
```

"address" is my wallet address and "assetUtxo" is the utxo where the fund is locked. Both are non nil.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `getUsedCollateral` isn't implemented yet on `AppWallet`.
It will be done really soon after we sort out other priorities.
for the time being, you can add Collateral from the Browser Wallet if possible

Comment: I assume you're in the team. Do you have an approximation of ETA? I really like working with mesh. AppWallet is much easier for my case.

Comment: Yes, you can expect it to be done within a month from now, maybe less. We will start working on it as soon as we finish the ongoing work we have right now.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly [glancing at Mesh code](https://github.com/MartifyLabs/mesh/blob/main/packages/module/src/wallet/app.service.ts#L87-L91) it looks like this function is not implemented yet and it might not be possible to create Plutus transactions just yet.

[image]

However the library is still under heavy development and I'm sure they will add this functionality soon.

Comment: Yeah, it is new. Any alternative to Mesh would you recommend?